# Why is CHECK Constraint not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a constraint to a table where one of the columns has to be one of the values from a list like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE bread_crumbs WITH CHECK
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_uplink_relationship
  CHECK (uplink_relationship in ('Cites', 'CitedBy', null))
```

I can still insert rows with any value for the `uplink_relationship` column.
The `CHECK` constraint is not being enforced.

I read a couple answers where this can happen if you create the constraint while there are rows that violate it.

So I deleted the constraint, fixed all the data, and added the constraint back in.

But no luck.

I can still enter invalid data.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Also, I tried with and without the `WITH CHECK` part of the statement.

Comment: SQL uses three valued logic. `true`, `false`, `unknown`. The check constraint is only violated if the condition evaluates to `false`.

Comment: `IN (null)` evaluates to `= NULL`; this is always unknown. You can't check if something is *equal to* `NULL`, only if it `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

*NULL* has to be handled separately

try a query

```
Select * from employee where empId in (1, 2, NULL) -- will result in 0 records

ALTER TABLE bread_crumbs
WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_uplink_relationship
CHECK (uplink_relationship in ('Cites','CitedBy') OR uplink_relationship IS NULL)
```

EDIT:

Read 
[SET ASI_NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for correction :) I will remove it